# efficiently growing atomic arrays

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Is there any clean and efficient way to grow an `Atomic(Double|Integer|Long|Reference)Array`? In my particular case there are no concurrent writes during copying. One obvious way to create a new one and copy the source array to the destination array in a loop:

```
Atomic*Array dest = new Atomic*Array(newSize);
for (int i = 0, len = src.length(); i < len; ++i)
    dest.set(i, src.get(i));
```

This code is likely much slower than a `System.arraycopy` or `Arrays.copy` type function and is also a bit verbose.

I could alternately use reflection to get the source's `array` field, extend it, and pass the new array into the Atomic*Array constructor:

```
try {
    Field arrayField = Atomic*Array.class.getDeclaredField("array");
    arrayField.setAccessible(true);
    ArrayType srcArray = (ArrayType)arrayField.get(src);
    Atomic*Array dest = new Atomic*Array(Arrays.copyOf(srcArray, newLength));
} catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
    throw new AssertionError(e);
}
```

But this code has problems too: it depends on the implementation of the `Atomic*Array` class, makes two copies of the array - one in `Arrays.copy` and one in `dest`'s constructor, and is very ugly.

Is there a faster/cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408112/get-the-array-from-an-atomiclongarray

Comment: You could grow by linking from the old to new array so that consumers can traverse. See JCTools' [MpscChunkedArrayQueue](https://github.com/JCTools/JCTools/blob/master/jctools-core/src/main/java/org/jctools/queues/MpscChunkedArrayQueue.java) for an example of this idea.

Comment: @BenManes Yes I thought of that idea but then memory usage is considerably higher as we need to wrap arrays in links, and the logic is a bit more complex because we need to maintain an approximate tail pointer. As is things are working decently with a single array but I would like to get as much performance out of this method as possible.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret Assuming an object array, wouldn't you stash forwarding link in the last index? Due to erasures, an ugly cast is worth the performance gain. Most of the time you'll be using the correct size and only pay the penalty when growing. Your other option is to use Unsafe until VarHandles arrive.

Comment: @BenManes You're right, you could store the next link in the last index. That's a good idea. Right, erasure means that casts are occurring anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm worry I'll disappoint you: there is no way how to copy `Atomic*Array` in batch.

Looking at [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html#AtomicIntegerArray(int[])), there is no method that would give you more than a single element at a time. Not even using the original array you can pass to `AtomicIntegerArray` constructor would help - the class makes a copy internally.

Looking at `AtomicIntegerArray` source code, using reflection could work - the class doesn't do anything special with the `array` field. I wouldn't, though. Not only is it usafe, but also reflection will give you some performance penalty you're trying to avoid.

If your goal is to grow the array, you may want to check out [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) or [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), depending on your use case.

I've ran a few times into this problem and we always found a way without an `Atomic*Array` in the end.

Comment: Thanks. My goal is to implement a very memory efficient, non-blocking append-only list. But unfortunately neither `LinkedBlockingQueue` nor `CopyOnWriteArrayList` meets my needs: the former uses far too much memory for its nodes and the latter is extremely inefficient. In fact no collection in the standard library fits my requirements.

Comment: Too bad you added the "non-blocking" requirement, otherwise you could also do with the good old `synchronized` :)

Comment: Right, `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())` would work but non-blocking is far preferable because the vast majority of the time there is no contention and so it's significantly faster (even with growing by copying in a loop :) ).

Comment: A lot of both. The collections can grow quite large so copy on write, with its quadratic performance, would be extremely slow. Also that strategy doesn't allow parallel writes, which is a problem. BTW my implementation performs roughly as fast as `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` and is significantly more memory efficient. (On the other hand it only supports appends and reads.)